# [Opencv Make Error]: ‘SolvePnPMethod’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘solvePnPRansac’?

Tags: opencv

I'm trying to install opencv 3.4.6 on ubuntu 18.04. My CUDA toolkit version is 10.2 with nvidia driver 470. I downloaded opencv in https://opencv.org/releases/ and downloaded opencv_contrib by `git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib.git` with `git checkout 3.4`. Then I ran cmake using

```
cmake -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
 -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
 -D OPENCV_GENERATE_PKGCONFIG=ON \
 -D ENABLE_CXX11=1  \
 -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=../opencv_contrib/modules \
 -D OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE=True \
 -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON \
 -D WITH_CUDA=ON \
 -D WITH_TBB=ON \
 -D ENABLE_FAST_MATH=1 \
 -D WITH_OPENMP=ON \
 -D WITH_CUFFT=ON \
 -D WITH_CUBLAS=ON \
 -D BUILD_opencv_cudacodec=OFF \
 -D CUDA_nppicom_LIBRARY=stdc++ \
 -DCUDA_ARCH_NAME=Manual \ 
 -DCUDA_ARCH_BIN="86" ..
```

The cmake process ran smoothly. However, during `make -j8` process, I encountered the following error: *‘SolvePnPMethod’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘solvePnPRansac’?*; *class ‘cv::aruco::EstimateParameters’ does not have any field named ‘solvePnPMethod’*

```
[ 22%] Built target opencv_bgsegm_pch_dephelp
Scanning dependencies of target opencv_test_cudaobjdetect_pch_dephelp
In file included from /home/lightwish/Downloads/opencv-3.4.6/opencv_contrib/modules/aruco/test/test_precomp.hpp:10,
                 from /home/lightwish/Downloads/opencv-3.4.6/build/modules/aruco/opencv_test_aruco_pch_dephelp.cxx:1:
/home/lightwish/Downloads/opencv-3.4.6/opencv_contrib/modules/aruco/include/opencv2/aruco.hpp:263:16: error: ‘SolvePnPMethod’ does not name a type
  263 |     CV_PROP_RW SolvePnPMethod solvePnPMethod;
      |                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/lightwish/Downloads/opencv-3.4.6/opencv_contrib/modules/aruco/include/opencv2/aruco.hpp: In constructor ‘cv::aruco::EstimateParameters::EstimateParameters()’:
/home/lightwish/Downloads/opencv-3.4.6/opencv_contrib/modules/aruco/include/opencv2/aruco.hpp:266:27: error: class ‘cv::aruco::EstimateParameters’ does not have any field named ‘solvePnPMethod’
  266 |                           solvePnPMethod(SOLVEPNP_ITERATIVE) {}
      |                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[ 22%] Building CXX object modules/cudaobjdetect/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_cudaobjdetect_pch_dephelp.dir/opencv_test_cudaobjdetect_pch_dephelp.cxx.o
make[2]: *** [modules/aruco/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_aruco_pch_dephelp.dir/build.make:63: modules/aruco/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_aruco_pch_dephelp.dir/opencv_test_aruco_pch_dephelp.cxx.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:14023: modules/aruco/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_aruco_pch_dephelp.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

I searched this error but didn't get the answer. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Please don't take screenshots of your code, errors or in this case stack traces. Instead you should include them in your question as text. That way it is easier for people to work with it. [ask]

Comment: My bad. I've edited my question as you suggested. Thanks for your advice!

Comment: Did you try to make without "-j"? Did you try to compile a current version of opencv/cuda? Any reason you need 3.4/10.2?

Comment: crosspost: https://forum.opencv.org/t/opencv-make-error-solvepnpmethod-does-not-name-a-type-did-you-mean-solvepnpransac/13213

Comment: @Markus I tried to make without "-j" and it failed as well. Today I tried opencv 4.2 with cuda 11.8 and successfully installed. The reason I initially chose 3.4/10.2 is that I want to re-implement my colleague's project, where the setup is exactly 3.4/10.2.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Thanks for the link. I tried opencv 4.2 with cuda 11.8 and successfully installed it, which had few errors.